# Make a jenkins build with conditional per branch parameter

Tags: git, jenkins

I currently have a jenkins job that builds my project from the develop branch. We follow a modified gitflow because of some technical constraints.

Anyway, basically what I want to do is to add a string parameter that takes a tagname and deploys from `refs/tags/${tagname}` **tagname** is of course the parameter. I want to make this parameter **optional** so that when this parameter is empty I build the development branch (not the tag).

One solution is duplicating this build job and making the configuration for the deployment with a parameter but I want to know if there is a way of modifying this job to make a build according to a tag (so a branch different than the develop branch)

I've tried looking everywhere but can't find any information on how to introduce an optional branch build according to a parameter in the source code management section of jenkins. I am checking multibranch pipeline configution currently...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **Conditional step** with the **Strings match** condition and use the `GIT_BRANCH` variable.

[image: Jenkins conditional step by branch name]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I will check this out

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar situation and for various reasons we did create two jobs (some job configs were also specific to TAG) & we had a parent job which would trigger the respective child job based on the input parameter, in this case your TAG name as param can decide which child job to be invoked